# LaTeX fragment preview includes font name in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

Since I have to export some CJK characters in LaTeX, I have the following two lines in an `.org` file :

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont]{xeCJK}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setCJKmainfont{HanaMinA}
```

However, this causes a weird display when I use `org-toggle-latex-fragment`.

[image: example]

You can
see that the font name is displayed above each maths expression.

### MWE

You must install HanaMinA fonts before testing. In Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install fonts-hanazono
```

Here is the minimal not working example I gave above:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[BoldFont,SlantFont]{xeCJK}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setCJKmainfont{HanaMinA}

The Euclid–Euler theorem is a theorem in mathematics that relates perfect
numbers to Mersenne primes. It states that every even perfect number has the
form $2^{p - 1}(2^p - 1)$, where $2^p - 1$ is a prime number. The theorem is named after
Euclid and Leonhard Euler.
```

How this problem can be solved?

**UPDATE**

I found a hint while I'm reading [one answer about "How to make a new tex command in org-mode-latex?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77830/125774). In short, everything involved with `#+LATEX_HEADER:` is taken account by the preview. Therefore, the question turns out to be how can I use packages for export only and not for preview? 
I have tried to move the two lines to an export latex block, but it doesn't work.